# Target table of DELETE is not updatable while deleting duplicates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, window-functions

I am writing this query using windows function `Row_Number()` which will find out duplicates and i am trying to `delete` those duplicates.

To do this i have written `CTE` and included window function it and attempting to delete duplicate row. However, i am getting error saying delete is not updatable.

```
select * from housingdata;
.
.
.
with rownumcte as (
select * ,row_number() over (partition by ParcelID, PropertyAddress, 
SalePrice,saledate,LegalReference  order by UniqueID) as rownum
from housingdata)
delete 
from rownumcte
where rownum>1;
```

if i use `select` instead of `delete` i am getting following output containing duplicates which is `104 rows`

[image]

Comment: please providr always a [mre] in text form or a dbfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes CTE are for many things very good, but for your purpose not.

Use instead a `INNER JOIN`.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE housingdata (UniqueID int, 
> ParcelID int
> , PropertyAddress varchar(50)
> , 
> SalePrice DECIMAL(10,2)
> ,saledate Date
> ,LegalReference int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO housingdata VALUES (1,1,'test',1.1, NOW(), 1),(2,1,'test',1.1, NOW(), 1)
> ```

> ```
> delete hd
> FROM housingdata hd INNER JOIN
>
> (
> select UniqueID ,row_number() over (partition by ParcelID, PropertyAddress, 
> SalePrice,saledate,LegalReference  order by UniqueID) as rownum
> from housingdata) t1 ON hd.UniqueID = t1.UniqueID 
> WHERE t1.rownum>1;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM housingdata
> ```
>
> ```
> UniqueID | ParcelID | PropertyAddress | SalePrice | saledate   | LegalReference
> -------: | -------: | :-------------- | --------: | :--------- | -------------:
>        1 |        1 | test            |      1.10 | 2022-02-25 |              1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2f60098f5a0090607f7261db74b8bf40)*

## UPDATE

You could have used also the CTE as joined table

> ```
> with rownumcte as (
> select UniqueID ,row_number() over (partition by ParcelID, PropertyAddress, 
> SalePrice,saledate,LegalReference  order by UniqueID) as rownum
> from housingdata)
> delete hd
> from housingdata hd INNER JOIN rownumcte r ON hd.UniqueID = r.UniqueID
> where rownum>1;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM housingdata
> ```
>
> ```
> UniqueID | ParcelID | PropertyAddress | SalePrice | saledate   | LegalReference
> -------: | -------: | :-------------- | --------: | :--------- | -------------:
>        1 |        1 | test            |      1.10 | 2022-02-25 |              1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba46eb6c4777c2c7c0c312cb11a842c8)*

Comment: @alex i added another version with CTE that you can use, only for completeness

Comment: sure, this works as well.